# Closing external application from vb6

Tags: vb6

I am opening ACAD application using below code :

Shell "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2011\acad.exe"

Now I want to close it.
Please help.

Comment: I think people should write the reason before giving negative points to particular post.We are here to get solution of our query not for any demotivation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698156/how-to-close-a-shelled-process-in-vb6

Comment: Thanks rags.Link was usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Const WM_QUIT As Long = &H12
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Shell "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2011\acad.exe", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Dim handle As Long
    handle = FindWindow("AutoCAD", vbNullString)
    If handle Then
        PostMessage handle, WM_QUIT, 0&, 0&
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the line:

```
FindWindow("AutoCAD", vbNullString)
```

You will have to change `"AutoCAD"` to whatever the name of the class is.  You can get the exact class name of AutoCAD using Spy++ or another equivalent program.

Another solution can be found here, which doesn't use Shell, but rather an API to keep track of the handle (which is far better, but could be more complex):

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=670